# UPDATE command from a where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I want to update a value from a database using SQL.

The table has 2 columns 'X' and 'Y'. What I want to do is to update Y having into account X. Example:
UPDATE table WHERE X = '1' AND SET Y = 'Test' WHERE warehousename = 'Hello'.

So I want to replace the value of Y from Hello to Test if value X = 1. I am not finding the solution, can you help me?

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The question is not clear.

Comment: At least, you are missing `SET <column> = <value>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I want to replace the value of Y from Hello to Test if value X = 1.

You would use:

```
update t
    set y = 'Test'
    where x = 1 and y = 'Hello';
```